# SNMP not working on Juniper ethernet switch

Tags: snmp, juniper

I need some help on configuring SNMP for Juniper EX4500 ethernet switch. I am performing this command:

```
host1:~# snmpwalk -v 2c -c my_community_string 192.168.1.1 .1
Timeout: No Response from 192.168.1.1
```

where `192.168.1.1` - switch's external IP address.

From the `host1` I am able to connect to other switch's ports such as 22.

SNMP agent looks to be running:

```
juniper> show system processes extensive | match snmp 
 2101 root         1  96    0 18860K 14628K select   0:06  0.00% snmpd
```

Also, I am able to query from the switch:

```
juniper> show snmp mib get 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.6.524 
ifHCInOctets.524 = 1200002682732106
```

SNMP configuration:

```
juniper> show configuration snmp 
location Switch;
community my_community_string {
    clients {
        10.5.1.3/32;
    }
}
```

where `10.5.1.3` - a host I'm connecting from

I would appreciate any help as I just lost in documentation and afraid to break something.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you are not NATting the connection towards that device ?

Comment: Sorry, my knowledge is very basic in this area. Could you tell me how to check on that?

Comment: I mean, is there an other network device between your snmp client and your Juniper stuff ? If yes, does it make NAT between the two network accidentally ?

Answer (score 1):

you're missing the authorization statement... set snmp community my_community_string authorization read-only

Comment: also, try "system" in your SNMPwalk instead of just .1

Comment: Thank you, it's important to set it read-only but that didn't help to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, I started to monitor switch by connecting to an internal IP address. I took it from the following configuration section:

```
unit 10 {        
    family inet {             
        address 10.11.11.1/16;  
    }
```